# Adobe  certifications: where can I do one, and will it help get me a job?

Tags: web-development, website-design, education

Where and which is the best way to do Adobe certifications? (Dreamweaver CS5 in India.)

Also, does it have weightage in getting a job?

Answer (score 2):

You can search for Adobe Certified Expert (ACE) training and test centers near you on the Pearson VUE website: http://www.pearsonvue.com/adobe/locate/

> Also, does it have weightage in getting a job?

A certificate in Dreamweaver tells a potential employer that you know how to use Dreamweaver. But there's more to Web development than knowing how to use software. A strong portfolio of design and development work is likely to carry more weight than a software certification, in my view.

Also consider that not all Web studios use Dreamweaver, and that some may prefer candidates who can demonstrate an ability to code using a simple text editor, without depending on a WYSIWYG development environment like Dreamweaver.